# Finitely generated extension implies finitely generated field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $K/F$ be a field extension. If $K$ is a finitely generated extension, namely $K=F[u_1,~\cdots,~u_n]$ for some $u_i\in K$. Then is $K$ also a finitely generated field(i.e. $K=\langle a_1,~\cdots,~a_m\rangle$ for some $u_i\in K$, where $\langle.\rangle$ means the subfield generated by the things inside)?

Comment: For a field extension $K/F$ we check if it is finitely generated as a field, as a ring (or $F$-algebra), as a $F$-vector space. For algebraic extensions the 3 are the same, for arbitrary extensions the last 2 are the same.

Comment: We need to check one thing. Presumably by $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_m\rangle$ you mean the smallest field **containing the field $F$** as well as the elements $a_1,\ldots,a_m$? For otherwise the claim is trivially false. $\Bbb{C}=\Bbb{R}(i)$ is a finitely generated extension, but $\Bbb{C}$ is not finitely generated as a field (for it has infinite transcendence degree over the prime field $\Bbb{Q}$).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I mean the smallest field containing $a_1,~\cdots,~a_m$. But I suddenly found that would be trivially true right? Every field is a PID, also every PID is Noetherian. So any field is definitely finite-generated is this sense?

Comment: Some confusion there. A ring is Noetherian if all its ideals are finitely generate. But generating an ideal is totally unrelated to generating a field. The ideal of, say, $\Bbb{R}$, generated by the number $3$ is all of $\Bbb{R}$ (by the reason you cited). But, the subfield of $\Bbb{R}$ generated by $3$ is $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh gosh. I see! Thanks for pointing out my confusion. Really helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K/F$ is a field extension where $K$ is finitely-generated as an $F$-algebra, then in fact $K/F$ is algebraic and finite-dimensional as an $F$-vector space. This is [Zariski's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma). In particular $K/F$ is finitely-generated as a field extension.

Be careful: the converse is far from being true though.

For example, say $K=\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ where $\pi=3.14...$. Since $\pi$ is transcendental, $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely-generated as a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra.